# composition. Pass a variables back

Tags: multithreading, oop, composition

Say you had two classes A and B. If the relationship between is has-a

i.e. A has-a B

how can you pass information from B into A? Say for example in B you work out a calculation and need the answer in A.

Is there any other way of doing this besides passing a pointer to class A into class B and calling a function which takes the answer as a parameter.

Hope this makes sense,

MD.

Sorry I should have been more specific

quote from my comment below.

"well I gave a simple example. I am programming this in java and my class B runs a new thread and and will calculate the answer. Therefore I cannot just call the function from class A as I don't know when the calculation will be completed."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method in A that needs the result of the computation should call into the method in B that does the computation.

<s>This answer is so obvious that there may be something you're not telling us (?)</s>

Ok, so the question is really about threading. Yes, then passing a reference to owner object and calling back into it may be a good idea. A better idea might be to return a [future object](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Futures_and_promises) that encapsulates the result of the computation.

Comment: well I gave a simple example. I am programming this in java and my class B runs a new thread and and will calculate the answer. Therefore I cannot just call the function from class A as I don't know when the calculation will be completed.

Comment: @mulletdevil: the addition of threads changing matters entirely. Updated my answer.

Comment: Apologies for being too vague. Thank you for the updated answer.

Comment: This is a good answer, I just want to add that B should use an interface that A implements.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have this kind of relationship:

```
class Car {
    Engine engine;

    int test() {
        int fuelLevel = engine.getFuelLevel();

        // do sth with fuel level, store it, use it etc.
   }
}
```

This example shows how can you pass information between the two classes: for instance as a result of function. Car object (your class A) calls a method on Engine object (class B) and int this way he obtains desired information. This can be easily translated to any kind of work that class B does.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to manage "asynchronous" calls.
The first is having a callback and the other polling.
Having a callback is what , you describe. When B has finished, it needs to call A somehow that it has finished. That can been done by "giving" the adress of A to B, so it knows what to call, or by using a intermediate object C, which calls B synchronously and send the result back to A. C then needs to know about A.

Polling is when A check regularly if B has finished. This solution is usually less satisfying intellectually and more CPU consuming. You are also not notified exactly when B finished. (When B finish, nothing happend, you'll have to wait for the next poll to be aware of it). However, that way , B doesn't need no know anything about A.

I would use the first pattern with an intermediate object (and special class C). So that your model is still clean (B doesn't need to know about A or C). I suggest also you have a look at the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).